# Ampscript UTF -8

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I want to store special characters like (<,>,",') in the data extension using ampscript. i have written a code and its updating the data extension bu the special characters are getting escaped. Ex: for < its storing as `&lt;` and > its storing as `&gt;`. Below is the code

```
%%[
set @rep = Replace("&lt;999","\&lt;","\<")
set @udpatedata = UpdateData("XML_Data_API",1,"FieldName","abhishek.j.mishra@gmail.com","XML_Data",@rep)

]%%
%%=v(@rep)=%%
```

Its updating the @rep value in data extension as `&lt;999` but i want the value to be stored as `<999`
Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: I had similar problems with &quot. Did you write this code in an email on the text-editor or the html editor. When i used the html editor it did not change the characters.  When i used the text editor it did. Maybe this helps.

Comment: i wrote this in cloud page and tried saving it in the data extension using ampscript @JohannesSchapdick

Comment: Have you tried writing in UTF-8-BOM in stead of UTF-8? I've seen this solving a lot of issues for me, when using special danish characters like æ, ø and å